# Compare two lists based on highest value and subsequent values?

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream, compare

I have two lists of:

```
List<Person> persons;
```

each Person has the attribute - `score`

e.g.

**list1:**

```
person.score = 3
person.score = 5
person.score = 8
```

**list2:**

```
person.score = 8
person.score = 4
person.score = 7
```

I want to compare each list to find the `highest` score in each. If both highest are the same, then I want to compare the second highest etc and so on.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a copy of each `List`, sort these copies, then compare them element by element.

```java
Comparator<List<Person>> comp = (a, b) -> {
    List<Person> s1 = a.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getScore).reversed()).toList(), 
                 s2 = b.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getScore).reversed()).toList();
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.size(), b.size()); i++) {
        int c = Integer.compare(s1.get(i).getScore(), s2.get(i).getScore());
        if (c != 0) return c;
    }
    return Integer.compare(a.size(), b.size());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a comparator to compare the lists. After, sorting each list, The comparator short circuits as soon corresponding scores are unequal, returning the value of the the last comparison.  Otherwise, if the two lists are equal or if if their sizes are different, the shortest list will return as the smaller.

**Details**

Since the score is the target of the comparison, I decided to grab it early and place in `int` arrays which are sorted.  Then I iterate over the arrays in reverse order to ensure I am testing the largest elements first (`IntStreams` can't take a comparator for sorting and I didn't want to box the `int` values).

Iterating over the lists, the scores are compared and the result is mapped to the stream.  Then the result of the comparison `(-1,0, or 1)` is filtered to ignore zero values, capturing the result in an `OptionalInt`.

Then either the `OptionalInt` value is returned, or the comparison of the array sizes.  Then, all comparisons being equal, the smaller array length would return `-1`, `larger 1`, and `equal lengths 0`

```
Comparator<List<Person>> listComp = (lst1, lst2) -> {
    int[] scores1 = lst1.stream().mapToInt(Person::getScore).sorted()
            .toArray();
    int[] scores2 = lst2.stream().mapToInt(Person::getScore).sorted()
            .toArray();
    
    OptionalInt diff = IntStream
            .iterate(Math.min(scores1.length-1, scores2.length-1),
                    i -> i >= 0, i -> i-1)
            .map(i -> Integer.compare(scores1[i], scores2[i]))
            .filter(delta -> delta != 0).findFirst();

    return diff.orElse(Integer.compare(scores1.length, scores2.length));
};
```

**Demos**

Some Data - comparing every two lists in the list of lists to each other. For demo purposes, I am using a `record` with a modified `toString()`.

```
record Person(int getScore) {
     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return "%d".formatted(getScore);
     }
}

List<List<Person>> lists = List.of(
        // first is smaller
        List.of(new Person(3), new Person(5), new Person(8)),
        List.of(new Person(8), new Person(4), new Person(7)),
        // equal lists
        List.of(new Person(3), new Person(7), new Person(8)),
        List.of(new Person(8), new Person(3), new Person(7)),
        // first is smaller due to length
        List.of(new Person(3), new Person(7), new Person(8)),
        List.of(new Person(8), new Person(3), new Person(7),
                new Person(2)));
```

To compare the lists, use `int result = listComp.compare(list1, list2);`

```
 int v;
 for (int i = 0; i < lists.size(); i += 2) {
     System.out.println(lists.get(i)
             + ((v = listComp.compare(lists.get(i), lists.get(i + 1))) > 0
                     ? " > "
                     : (v < 0) ? " < " : " == ")
             + lists.get(i + 1));
 }
```

prints the following:

```
[3, 5, 8] < [8, 4, 7]
[3, 7, 8] == [8, 3, 7]
[3, 7, 8] > [8, 3, 7, 2]
```